# filter listView containing sms list with contacts

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a listView created using SimpleCursorAdapter.

```
lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myList);
    lv.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_INSET);
    //Cursor c = this.getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse( "content://sms/conversations?simple=true"), null, null, null, "normalized_date desc" );
    final Uri inboxURI = Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations/");
    final String[] reqCols = new String[] { "_id", "address", "body" };
    final String[] projection = new String[]{"*"};

    cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor c = cr.query(inboxURI, projection, null, null, Telephony.Sms.Inbox.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);
    madapter = new simpleLayout(this, R.layout.list_row, c, new String[] { "body", "address" }, new int[] {R.id.text_msg, R.id.phone_number });
    lv.setAdapter(madapter);
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

I have also added filter to the listview

```
madapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
        public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {                           
            return getContentResolver().query(inboxURI, reqCols, "address" + " LIKE '" + constraint + "%'", null, null);
        }
    });
```

before the listView only contained the address but now I have mapped them with real contact numbers so the filter is not working any more. How should I return the query so that it will work again

Comment: actually,  what's the problem?

Comment: the listview before had address now I have mapped the address with actual contact numbers but the filter query contains address so how to make a query so that the searchview would filter actual contact numbers